# Different order of eigenvalues computed with PCA and SVD

Tags: python, pca, svd

I really don't know why, when i computed the eigenvalues with PCA from my dataset i obtain a vector which have values in different order respect of SVD

This is the result
[image]

This is the code
[image]

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Please provide more context/background information, and please do not post screenshots of your code (paste and format the actual code instead). Also, this question as a whole might be better suited to [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PCA is incomplete when you use `np.linalg.eig` because after eigen-decomposition you have to reorder the terms so the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix are in descending order (this is not part of the eigen-decomposition itself). Furthermore, the [eig docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) do not guarantee any order in your results, whereas the [SVD docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) explicitly state that your values are returned in descending order.